# How do I automate authentication on a site that uses a third party like github or Facebook for login credentials when scraping?

Tags: authentication, oauth

I am trying to scrape a webpage on codeeval.com that shows which challenges a user has completed and which ones are not completed. The page is https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/ The problem is that I use my github account to log into codeeval.com. I can't figure out how to authenticate my scraper through github so that I can get to that page. Currently I need to manually login and save the HTML file. I'd like to automate the process.

I'm using scrapy and python.

Comment: You can use selenium for this process. If you are familiar with it. [This Link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/installation.html) holds the answer to your question.Give it a shot and need more help post it again

Comment: @JohnDene Thanks. I have used it before, and I do think I could figure out how to get the flow correct to make this work. In the meantime, I am looking into this: https://github.com/joestump/python-oauth2 - I'm not sure if this is going to turn out to be more complicated than it is worth, but for now it's an exercise to see if I can make this happen or not.

Comment: Good keep working. I think this is very easy if you just selenium.